# Font Awesome 5 (SVG): jQuery toggleClass not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I'm unable to toggleClass on a font awesome element. How do we go about doing this? The <i> element gets converted to a <svg> element. I'm only able to toggle the class once and then after that it doesn't work. Here is the code: https://codepen.io/overdrivemachines/pen/jOmaggK

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="post-actions">
    <i class="fa fa-heart like-32 fa-2x post-like active" data-id="32"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="post-actions">
    <i class="fa fa-heart like-33 fa-2x post-like" data-id="33"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="post-actions">
    <i class="fa fa-heart like-34 fa-2x post-like" data-id="34"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.post-actions {
  margin: 20px;
  background: #fee; 
  i, svg {
    color: #ddd;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  i:hover, svg:hover {
    color: #999;
  }
  i.active, svg.active {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

```js
$(function () {
  $(".post-like").on("click", function () {
    var post_id = $(this).data("id");
    console.log(post_id);
    $(this).toggleClass("active");   
  });  
});
```

Comment: `$(".post-actions").on("click", 'svg.post-like', function () {`

Comment: Thank you that works. But Why is $(".post-like").on("click" ...) not working? Why do we have to use it on the parent element?

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe when you bind the action to the element (to .post-like) it triggers, but then the whole div will change because of the svg convertion so maybe it happens AFTER the bind so logic will be lost. Maybe the convert process will remove temporarily the div and append it after it finished so that's why, because that div doesn't exist anymore. It seems logical to me.

Comment: its called event delegation, font awsome replaces the element so the original event is placed on the svg but there is not an event on the replaced svg so it only fires once, is in the docs https://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler